# Django ListView pagination when passing multiple objects in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-pagination

I'm working on Django app and currently ran into a problem.
I have my ListView as:

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
  template_name = "categories.html"

  def get_queryset(self):
     ...
     ...
     queryset = {"category": parent, "items": items.all()}
     return queryset
```

Is there any walkaround for paginating "items" from queryset dict? Because when I set `paginate_by = xx` I get error `unhashable type: 'slice'`. What is, from my understanding, and it's pretty obvious cause by the fact that it doesn't know what if I request to paginate "category" or "items".

Thank you for every input.

Michal

Comment: Your best option is to reorganize your logic so that you're not trying to return two things from `get_queryset` which should only return 1 thing.

Comment: Honestly, I was thinking about that a lot before posting this question, but I can't find any way to do what I want to do with just one queryset. Even after reorganizing Models.

Comment: Please help us to understand why you want to set `category` in `get_queryset`. Why cannot you save `self.parent=parent` and set `context["parent"] = self.parent` in `get_context_data()` ?

Answer (score 0):

when you use the get_queryset method it should return Queryset that will be used to retrieve the object that this view will display.

if you want passing multiple objects in queryset use get_context_data method

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class CategoryView(ListView):
    template_name = "categories.html"
    model = Category # category model
    paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items'] = items.all()
        return context
```